# How to enable cordova app to listen to a voice "Ok Cordova" to activate the speech recognition

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I want to make an app that executes speech recognition whenever the app hear that i say "OK Cordova"

Any suggestion on how to implement this kind of app as well as the resources you
know would be much appreciated

The approach used by others is by using a button. But for me its better to just listen to a fixed word to start the speech recognition